# Program stops printing one character at a time from two strings after the Characters are printed from the shorter string

Tags: java, string, loops, java.util.scanner, charat

I have a problem with this code. Otherwise it does exactly what the title says, but if the given strings are "aa" and "bbbb", it prints just "abab" instead it should print "ababbb". The program seems to stop after the characters are printed from the shorter string. Here's the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Anna merkkijono: ");
    String merkkijono1 = lukija.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Anna toinen merkkijono: ");
    String merkkijono2 = lukija.nextLine();
    for (int index = 0; index < merkkijono1.length() || index < merkkijono2.length(); index++) {
        if (merkkijono1.length() > index) {
            System.out.print(merkkijono1.charAt(index));
            if (merkkijono2.length() > index) {
                System.out.print(merkkijono2.charAt(index));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So somehow i should make it continue even when the Characters are printed from the shorter string, any tips?

Also for some reason one of the brackets didn't fit into the code text and i wasn't able to include the java.util.Scanner and public class without turning the whole code text into a mess, sorry about that.

Comment: Theres no need to nest the two `if` statement. Unnest them and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the if statement was inside the wrong loop.
Here, I tested it and it works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Anna merkkijono: ");

        String merkkijono1 = lukija.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Anna toinen merkkijono: ");

        String merkkijono2 = lukija.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < merkkijono1.length() || i < merkkijono2.length(); i++) {

            if (merkkijono1.length() > i) {
                System.out.print(merkkijono1.charAt(i));

            }
            if (merkkijono2.length() > i) {
                System.out.print(merkkijono2.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the second if-statement out of the first one.

```
for (int index = 0; index < merkkijono1.length() || index < merkkijono2.length(); index++) {
    if (merkkijono1.length() > index) {
        System.out.print(merkkijono1.charAt(index));
    }
    if (merkkijono2.length() > index) {
        System.out.print(merkkijono2.charAt(index));
    }
}
```